# Why does lint come into our bathroom when the dryer is running

Tags: dryer

Why does dryer lint come into my bathroom through the air vent?  Is there a leak in the dryer vent pipe?  We just got our dryer vent cleaned.

Comment: Is it coming through the exhaust fan in the bathroom? Is it possible that the dryer, and the exhaust fan share a duct?

Comment: we need to know what kind of vent you have in the bedroom  and if it is an open vent or a fan forced exhaust vent. Does this vent go into the ceiling?  more detailed info please